# SQL Server 2008 Pivot Without aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table `UserRoleTable` and it has columns `ID`, `JobId`, `ProjectManager`, `Engineer`:

```
**ID     JobId      Engg      Manager**

001    1001       x         Null
002    1002       Null      P
003    1003       Y         Q
004    1004       Z         Null
005    1005       Null      J
```

I want the result in this format:

```
ID     JobId      Name      Role

001    1001       x         Engg
002    1002       P         Manager
003    1003       Y         Engg
003    1003       Q         Manager
004    1004       Z         Engg
005    1005       J         Manager
```

There are no primary or foreign keys involved.

Should I use `Pivot` for this functionality?

Comment: FYI This is more of an unpivot since your column header is becoming values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES` to unpivot the data:

```
select id, jobid,
    name,
    role
from UserRoleTable
cross apply
(
    values ('Engg', engg), ('Manager', Manager)
) c (role, name)
where name is not null;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2dcae/1)

Or you can use the `UNPIVOT` function:

```
select id, jobid, name, role
from UserRoleTable
unpivot
(
  name
  for role in (Engg, Manager)
) unpiv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2dcae/2)

And here is a `UNION` solution:

```
  SELECT id, jobid, Engg AS name, 'Engg' AS role
    FROM UserRoleTable
    WHERE Engg IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT id, jobid, Manager, 'Manager'
    FROM UserRoleTable
    WHERE Manager IS NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY id, role ;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2dcae/18)

Comment: @user2438237 `PIVOT` is the more elegant of the two answers. I'd try them both with your data sets and see which has the better performance profile.

Comment: @bluefeet: Thnks a lot. it is running perfectly fine. I am not well aware of cross apply, pivot, unpivot commands. Seems like I have to learn them. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @user2438237 ... not to mention the backward case logic.